# Getting X and Y values of Markers From Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create simple Map application to display our field captured points on the map.So far I have all Data in a json file and I am able to display them on Map.Please take a look at This <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/J2B3K/2/)**</kbd>
What I want to do is editing the X Y coordinates on the map so I need to 
1- Grab X Y from existing Markers **on MAP** and Display them on the Table
2- Focus on the related `<tr>` in the Table When Click on the associated Marker
3- As the Markers Position get updated the related data in the table also get updated.

I already tried this:

```
$('.'+marker.id).html('<td>'+ marker.title +'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lat()+'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lng()+'</td>');  });
$('#myTable tbody:eq(1)').append('<tr class='+marker.id+'><td>'+ marker.title +'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lat()+'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lng()+'</td></tr>'); });
```

but it didn't work! Can you please let me know how I can do this?

Update:
 I tried to alert the lat() of one of markers as:

```
locations.length = 0;
for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: new  google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude),
 map: map,
 title:"marker "+p
 });

 $( "button" ).click(function() {
    alert(marker[1].position.lat());
});
}
```

and I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Comment: I also tried to get alert lat() for one of markes like this:                 $( "button" ).click(function() {
    alert(marker[p].position.lat());
});  which I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Comment: Where is that button supposed to be? We don't see it in your code. What are you trying to do exactly? What is supposed to be displayed in that table? All markers positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `marker.position` you should use `marker.getPosition()`

Also in this code here, you refer to `marker[1]` in the click handler function as if it were an array, which it isn't.

```
for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude, data.markers[p].longitude),
        map: map,
        title: "marker " + p
    });

    $("button").click(function () {
        alert(marker[1].position.lat());
    });
}
```

Essentially what it looks like you're trying to say is, for every single `<button>`, when clicked, I want to alert the position of each marker.  Which is a bit daft (and also this code won't work anyway).

Here's an updated answer following some online chat with the OP to clarify requirements

```
for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude, data.markers[p].longitude),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: "marker " + p,
        id: p
    });

    $('#myTable tbody:eq(1)').append('<tr class=' + marker.id + '><td>' + marker.title + '</td><td>' + data.markers[p].latitude + '</td><td>' + data.markers[p].longitude + '</td></tr>');

    bindMarker(marker);
}

function bindMarker(marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
        $('tr.' + this.id).html('<td>' + this.title + '</td><td>' + this.getPosition().lat() + '</td><td>' + this.getPosition().lng() + '</td>');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        // turn off the highlighting on whichever row had it previously 
        $('tr.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');

        // and add it to this marker's row 
        $('tr.' + this.id).addClass('highlighted');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Duncan, and thanks for your comment but This is also not working! I update the Fiddle as : http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/J2B3K/3/ but as you can see I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined " error again!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your button click handler.  You're going to add multiple markers, but you only have one button.  What do you want the button to do (other than what you're attempting just now - outputting latitudes)?

Comment: You are right it was just a try! I do not mean to gab any data from button click what I want to do is loading a table values after loading markers to map

Comment: Can you please forget the button part and consider the my main question regarding to this post?

Comment: See my updated answer; you seem to be doing two things where you're adding the same HTML to your page - I think you only require the second one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44157/discussion-between-behseini-and-duncan)